# Can someone explain why wordpress uses two column for storing time values?

Tags: date-time, timestamp, timezones

I see two table columns in wordpress tables for time values.

Examples:

`post_date` `post_date_gmt`

`post_modified` `post_modified_gmt`

`comment_date` `comment_date_gmt`

What is the reason behind storing different time types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `post_date` is the `post_date_gmt` after the Timezone value (in Settings) has been applied.

So, if you like, the reasoning is that there's a *standard time for everybody*, and then *your own site's time depending on your Settings*, so say you want to change that later, the *standard time* is always left untouched.